# magento stock status, out of stock item not changing even the quantity is greater the 0

Tags: magento, updates, status, stock

hello i am not a big expert of magneto but would like some like from expert of magento.
i have version 1.9 loaded 
the problem is i update the stock via csv file.
when the item goes 0 it change to "out of stock" but when the quantity increase greater the 0 it dont change to in stock. it still says on my control panel quantity 29 "out of stock". and all out of stock items do not show on our front end. so i am losing customers on item which i actually have in stock.
any idea how can i resolve this issue please?
magento should change the status automatically when quantity become greater then 0.
thank you guys 
i hope you will help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it's a feature. When an item's stock is depleted, and you replace the stock, you have to set the stock level, *and* specify that the item is once again **in stock**.

You can bypass this by changing the settings in Admin, at **System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory**. See both **Stock Options** and **Product Stock Options** in this menu.

By the way, you will find dedicated Magento help over at https://magento.stackexchange.com/

**EDIT**

---

It depends how you are updating the stock qty? The stock qty field is `product[stock_data][qty]`, and the **stock status** field is `product[stock_data][is_in_stock]`. If you are automating an update to qty, you can add an update for stock status (`= 1`).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, but i have check these options and i canot find any thing which can solve this issue. can you please tell in bit more detail please?

Comment: You can either enable backorders, or you can introduce a code modificatoin, similar to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168295/magento-auto-changing-the-stock-availability-from-out-of-stock-to-in-stock?rq=1

Comment: i have read that question as well but this is unsolved as well. been looking for help for long time. please advise.

Comment: i dont see where i can change it so i dont have to manage stock when its above zero